# Why do I get "Error: object expected" when trying to call jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Code produces an "error object expected" on:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >
    var doRedirect = function() { location.href='http://www.google.com' };
    $("#<%=Button1.ClientId%>").click(function() {
        $("#<%=Label1.ClientId%>").show();
        window.setTimeout("$('#<%=Label1.ClientId%>').fadeOut('slow', doRedirect)", 10000);
    });
    </script>
```

What is wrong in this code?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="color: #009933; font-weight: 700">

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    <p style="color: #336600; font-weight: 700">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </p>
    </form>
     <script type ="text/javascript" >
         var doRedirect = function() { location.href='http://www.google.com' };
         $("#<%=Button1.ClientId%>").click(function() {
             $("#<%=Label1.ClientId%>").show();
             window.setTimeout("$('#<%=Label1.ClientId%>').fadeOut('slow', doRedirect)", 10000);
         });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ClixNCash - you should at least explain what the code is *supposed to do*, and what it *actually does*.

Comment: And list the exact compiler error and indicate the line it occurs on.

Comment: I have already indicated the error code ///// above ...

Comment: You didn't do a good job of making it clear.  I cleaned it up for you by putting quotes around the error message.  Writing good, clean questions will help you get better, faster, smarter answers.

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to include a jQuery reference inside your `<head>`

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=609

Answer (score 2):

IF you do have jQuery and that is not the problem, you will not be able to make a label appear using javascript if you have it hidden server side...

This will not be part of the page, so you cannot just make it visible:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

You could hide it like this perhaps

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

Does that help?